# Python Wordle solver

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordle

I created a Python script that solves Wordle (more specifically this version: https://mywordle.org), it uses a wordlist of all possible answers, it is working perfectly and it rarely loses,  you can see it in action [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-vHBVZNF3ptyaB37V0SoU8RmPzlQlWHX/view?usp=sharing) (Google Drive).

You will need [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oAJfmk3eraojXXAaO4hql0maU-V7ArCk/view?usp=sharing), I obtained it by editing this file: https://mywordle.org/f5.txt?v=0.2.0.

The Script:

```py
import random
import re
import time
from copy import deepcopy
from pathlib import Path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from string import ascii_lowercase

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
capabibilties = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabibilties['pageLoadStrategy'] = 'eager'
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 1)

Firefox = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabibilties, options=options, firefox_profile=profile)
wait = WebDriverWait(Firefox, 3)

grid = "//div/div[contains(@class, 'game-grid')]"
cell = grid + "/div[contains(@class, 'game-item')]"

states = {
    'bg-gray-400': 'absent', 
    'bg-orange-400': 'present',
    'bg-green-500': 'correct'
}

wordlelist = Path('D:/corpus/wordle-5.txt').read_text().splitlines()

class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = deepcopy(wordlelist)
        self.letters = ascii_lowercase
        self.pattern = ''
        self.present = set()
    
    def guess(self):
        return random.choice(self.pool)
    
    def update(self, conditions):
        pool = list()
        self.process(conditions)
        for word in self.pool:
            if re.match(self.pattern, word):
                if not self.present or all(l in word for l in self.present):
                    pool.append(word)
        self.pool = pool
    
    def process(self, conditions):
        for letter, state in conditions:
            if state == 'absent':
                self.letters = self.letters.replace(letter, '')
        
        pattern = []
        self.present.clear()
        for letter, state in conditions:
            if state == 'absent':
                pattern.append('[' + self.letters + ']')
            elif state == 'present':
                pattern.append('[' + self.letters.replace(letter, '') + ']')
                self.present.add(letter)
            elif state == 'correct':
                pattern.append(letter)
        
        self.pattern = '^' + ''.join(pattern) + '$'


def solve():
    agent = Agent()
    correct_status = ['bg-green-500'] * 5
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, grid)))
    for i in range(6):
        guess = agent.guess()
        Firefox.find_element('xpath', '//body').send_keys(guess)
        Firefox.find_element('xpath', '//body').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        cells = Firefox.find_elements('xpath', cell)
        time.sleep(2)
        status = [c.find_element('xpath', './div[2]').get_attribute('class').split()[2] for c in cells[i*5:i*5+5]]
        if status == correct_status:
            break
        status = [states[s] for s in status]
        agent.update(list(zip(guess, status)))
    time.sleep(3)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[1]/div[1]/button[3]')))
    Firefox.find_element('xpath', '//div[1]/div[1]/button[3]').click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Firefox.get('https://mywordle.org')
    time.sleep(3)
    while True:
        solve()
```

I wrote this script in under 3 hours all by myself, the part of the script that I want to get reviewed is the class `Agent`. It can work with other front-end as well, I am perfectly capable of writing a full-fledged working GUI Wordle game using PyQt6, but nah I am lazy.

I want to know how I can improve the logic, algorithm, efficiency et cetera of that particular class.